# jasper responds only to espeak voice not human voice

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I am using Raspberry pi raspbian jessie pixel OS with jasper and using stt pocketsphinx and espeak tts.
Now when i hit ./jasper.py in terminal it start successfully but doesn't respond to human voice, but when I hit "espeak jasper" in the other terminal it returns just "high beep" nothing else. 
Any help how to debug it, or resolve this problem.

Comment: It is not clear, which version of jasper you are using. what do you mean by other terminal ? to debug run jasper with --debug flag.

Comment: i have croned jasper from https://github.com/jasperproject and  i have also tried debugging it. it runs locally fine too. but using mic it dont listen to me. It was running fine before. But then I added it to crontab @reboot. And after then suddenly it stopped giving any response. pocket sphinx is  working perfectly. I checked mic too. arecord, aplay and espeak is also working fine. but jasper don't listen my voice. thank you.

Comment: ok so what error did you see in jasper debug log?

Comment: There is no error but I get stuck at 'No disturbance detected'. and when i use espeak for speaking jasper . it sometimes understands it even without connecting mic. but do not detect my voice . if that is any problem of audio or some other?

Comment: I have looked for the same in many forums. jasper google groups, github issues but could not find it. as i used it before successfully , i didn't came across such thing so do not know where to go now. but it shows cant open slave before 'how can i be of service ' is spoken.

Comment: better put more details about USB Mic you are using, asoundrc file content, arecord command you used to record, amixer/alsamixer output for USB Sound card, jasper debug log, .....

Comment: I have put some tips about alsa setup on Jessie, take a look here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/robocopai

Comment: thank you for help. here is my .asoundrc file `pcm.!default {
 type hw
 card 0 
}

ctl.!default {
 type hw
 card 0
}`     i can record with command `arecord -D plughw:1,0 b.wav` and play with `aplay b.wav` .. alsamixer is set to 100% for capture and master both. but i also tried with 50% capture as i read somewhere 100% mic volume makes harder to recognize. and this is jasper debug log `INFO:client.conversation:Starting to handle conversation with keyword 'GLINT'.
DEBUG:client.conversation:Started listening for keyword 'GLINT'
No disturbance detected`

Comment: i am using same mic as http://www.ebay.in/itm/322460675472?aff_source=Sok-Goog

Comment: ok try this alsa config in your .asoundrc and replace  card U0x46d0x825 with card 1. reboot and test again.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robocopai/YDVGFcu_NOs

Comment: thanks for all the help.. it started working after i changed the value of cards in asoundrc.. :)